# Android SMTP mail sender with SSL ignore

Tags: java, android, ssl, jakarta-mail

Iam trying to use the JavaMail examples found online to send emails from my Android application using a custom SMTP server. The SMTP server does not have a valid SSL certificate, instead it uses a self signed one so when I try to connect I get an SSL Handshake exception.

I tried to use the :

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
```

properties but then I get the error:

```
E/SendMail(17874): Could not connect to SMTP host: {MY_SMTP_HOST}, port: {MY_SMTP_PORT}, response: -1
```

Any suggestions? Is there any other library that supports sending emails through SMTP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581066/using-javamail-with-a-self-signed-certificate

Comment: @CommonsWare It doesn't seem to work. I still get the "..response -1" error

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  The latest version is [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  Please post the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).