# Error In Sending Mail through SMTP from Cpanel

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail to a gmail as smpt from my host service but stacktrace says

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587;
```

Though the code is working fine when executed on my Eclipse IDE. I asked hosting services if there any firewall that could be stopping the same. But they denied it by saying that your ip is not blocked in firewall and given port is also open on server and able to connect to the remote servers. Then what could be the reason for the problem. Here is the code

```
final String username = "xyz@gmail.com";
        final String password = "abcd";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                password);
                    }
                });
        out.print(session);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    "abc@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("hello");
            message.setText("this is me");
            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            out.print(mex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you include one more properties and try again? `properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");`

Comment: yea sure :) fingers crossed @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: Have you tried logging into a shell on the host machine and establishing a telnet connection to the destination address on port 587?

Comment: Does it works? @MayankVaid

Comment: @RichardSchwartz No I didn't. And i don't konw exactly how to do it. Could you be more specific :)

Comment: No it didn't worked :( @AtaurRahmanMunna

Comment: In my case i used for initializing msg as, don't sure if that works.
`Message message = new MimeMessage(session);`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614793/error-in-sending-email-through-smtp

Comment: And you also need to disable security for third party apps.

Comment: I disable all security and still no success. Host service says that firewall allows all three ports so Its a development side issue @sameerasy

Comment: Log into a shell on your hosted system. Try the command 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 25'. Does the connection succeed? You should get a response that starts with something like this: '220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP'