# sending mail in background in android 4.4.4 KitKat source code(android)

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app that send email without user interaction..
I get the error which you can see. please help whats the cause of it.

this is my mail.java

```
package com.example.javamail;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 

import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
    this._to= toArr;

}

public void setFrom(String string) {
    this._from = string;

}

public void setSubject(String string) {
    this._subject = string;

} 
}
```

automaticMailActivity

```
package com.example.javamail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class automaticMailActivity extends Activity {
    private Mail m;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        Button sendmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email);

        sendmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) { 
                m = new Mail("wahidullah.mdr@gmail.com", "password");

                  String[] toArr = {"wahidullah.mdr@gmail.com"}; 
                  m.setTo(toArr); 
                  m.setFrom("mujibjan@gmail.com"); 
                  m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
                  m.setBody("Email body."); 

                  try { 
//                  m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

                    if(m.send()) { 
                      Toast.makeText(automaticMailActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } else { 
                      Toast.makeText(automaticMailActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    } 
                  } catch(Exception e) { 
                    Toast.makeText(automaticMailActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    Log.e("automaticMailActivity", "Could not send email", e); 
                  } 
                } 
              }); 
    }
}
```

my XML file 
actvity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.javamail.automaticMailActivity" >


    >
<Button android:id="@+id/send_email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Email"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but i have still some problems that shown as follow:

```
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366): Could not send email
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366): javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   nested exception is:
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com:465
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1389)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.example.javamail.Mail.send(Mail.java:104)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.example.javamail.automaticMailActivity$1.onClick(automaticMailActivity.java:34)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: smtp.gmail.com:465
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1038)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:997)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
03-08 23:08:11.800: E/automaticMailActivity(366):   ... 19 more
```

Comment: And what's your question again ?

Comment: I dont know whats the reason of the error. please see above the error.

Answer (score 0):

465 port use for SSL so i think you getting something error here , instead of you can try 587 port with TLS (not SSL) to send mail.

Try code bellow:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  // If you need to authenticate
// Use the following if you need SSL
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

and read more at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411331/using-javamail-with-tls)